# Filling in explicit zeros in a (x,y) list for nonexisting y values for discrete Fourier transform in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, fourier-analysis

I have a list of (x,y) values in Mathematica for various discrete x values, as in

```
intensities={{26, 10}, {27, 289}, {28, 90}, {29, 1079}, {30, 30}, {33, 10}, {39, 
  179}, {40, 40}, {41, 2269}}
```

I would now like to insert into this list explicit zeros for each discrete value of x that has a nonexisting y value, as in

```
intensities2={{0,0},{1,0},{2,0},....,{26,10},{27,289},{28,90},...,{41,2269}}
```

Out of these I would then like to extract just the y values to be able to do a discrete Forier transform on them. Any thoughts how I could do this most efficiently?

cheers & many thanks for any advice!
Tom

Comment: Something like this can be used to get zeroes with specific values altered. `ilist = ConstantArray[0, Max[intensities[[All, 1]]]];
Map[(ilist[[#[[1]] + 1]] = #[[2]]) &, intensities];`

Comment: @PlatoManiac: yes, sorry - I edited it now...

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, since Tom wants the x values to start at 0, shouldn't you use `ilist=ConstantArray[0,1+intensities[[-1,1]]];Map[(ilist[[#[[1]]+1]]=#[[2]])&,intensities];` ?  This then gives `ilist` as the answer Tom wants I think.  This is a simpler solution than the one I posted below, but after all these years I still find the myriad uses of `Map` hard to understand.

Comment: @JasonB Yes one can alter that code to get a list of ordered pairs. I had indeed skipped that and gone directly to "extract[ing] just the y values".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this!

```
Normal@SparseArray[{#1} -> #2 & @@@ intensities]
```

Be careful that it works if the list `intensities2` starts with `{1,x}` not `{0,x}` and input list `intensities` has no entries like `{0,x}`.

If you persist on starting `intensities2` with `{0,x}` and given that input list `intensities` will have increasing x values then try the following

```
With[{zero = First@#},
    If[zero[[1]] === 0,
        ({zero[[2]]}~Join~SparseArray[{#1} -> #2 & @@@ Rest[#]]),
        {0}~Join~SparseArray[{#1} -> #2 & @@@ #]
  ]
 ] &@intensities; // AbsoluteTiming
```

In order to check efficiency you will need to create bigger example data. You can do so using the following.

```
samplesize = 10^6; 
intensities =Sort@Transpose@(RandomSample[#,samplesize] &/@
(Range[0, #] & /@ {10 samplesize,10 samplesize}));
```

Comment: Many thanks for this - brilliant! I like the other answers too, but this one is really compact! I always have trouble coming up with such compact solutions, typically resorting to old school Do loops :-)

Comment: Slick (and an upvote).

Answer (score 2):

belisarius's answer is more elegant I'm sure, but I like a straightforward use of `Table` and `Do` whenever possible.

```
intensities={{26,10},{27,289},{28,90},{29,1079},{30,30},{33,10},{39,179},{40,40},{41,2269}};
intensities2=Table[{n,0},{n,0,intensities[[-1,1]]}];
Do[
  intensities2[[intensities[[n,1]]+1]]=intensities[[n]];
  ,{n,Length[intensities]}]
```

Then when you want to extract just the second column of the data, just the y values, you use

```
intensities2[[All,2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(Join[{#, 0} & /@ Complement[Range@Max@#[[All, 1]], #[[All, 1]]], #] &@ints)[[All,2]]
```

Comment: in your post, is `ints` equal to OP's `intensities`?  Also, it seemed to work better before the edit, although it didn't give the `{0,0}` element.  When I enter what you have now, I only get the second column.

Comment: @JasonB _"Out of these I would then like to extract just the y values"_ ...

Comment: yeah I saw that after I made this comment.  I'm still confused about whether the OP needed the x values to start at 0 or 1.  In his question it seemed that he wanted it to start at 0, so the resulting answer should be a one-dimensional list with 42 elements.  But the answer he accepted doesn't fit that criteria.

Comment: @JasonB I edited my answer to fit the case you mentioned.

Comment: @JasonB Me neither, but it's _his_ question :)